# Orden de carga de Scripts en mi web

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una serie de JS con diferentes funciones que dependen de que jquery se cargue correctamente. Esto funciona perfecto desde los CDNs pero en caso que el CDN falle jquery se carga desde mi servidor pero se carga al final en el DOM, a pesar de estar casi al inicio del head.

¿Hay alguna manera de forzar que siempre cargue jquery al inicio?

Así tengo el html

```html
<head>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="es/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">x3C/script>')</script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  ....
  <body>
  ............-------
  Al final de mi body mis script
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./es/js/funcion1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./es/js/javascript2.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que el script que está en esta sección:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="es/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">x3C/script>')</script>
```

ocurre primero, pues no depende de ser descargado de un archivo externo, y al hacer la evaluación de `window.jQuery` está `ùndefined` por lo tanto hará la inserción del script en el documento.

Te recomiendo que te decidas de si usar jQuery desde un CDN o desde tu propio servidor.

Comment: Quería tener la opción de cargar jquery desde mi servidor en caso que el CDN no responda. - pero que si se da el caso del fallo del CDN se cargue primero mi archivo jquery que otros scripts de mi página. pero por alguna causa a pesar de tenerlo al inicio termina cargándose al final.

Comment: Dificilmente el CDN no va a responder, pero si tanto le preocupa, mejor consuma el archivo desde su propio servidor.